# How to keep casting video using airplay using flutter when we switch apps

Tags: ios, flutter, video, background-process, airplay

In flutter I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_to_airplay/example  package to cast videos on apple tv , it works fine but when I switch between apps it stops the video and casting . I have tried to unable the **background mode** in Xcode but still it pauses the video when some other app is opened  [image: Xcode Background Modes]

In flutter I am using the code in this way ,

```
 AirPlayRoutePickerView(
  tintColor: Colors.white,
  activeTintColor: Colors.white,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, )
```

What I need to change so that the videos keep playing when we switch between apps.

I have tried background modes and flutter pub dev two packages **flutter_to_airplay** and **flutter_ios_airplay** but for both videos and the casting stops when I switch between apps ,
May there is some change in iOS configuration .